# How can I combine OpenLDAP trees for user authentication?

Tags: ldap, authentication, openldap

Let's say I'm running two OpenLDAP servers which I can use independently for authentication: ldap.example.com (a production site) and ldap.example.io (a testing site).

Is it possible to configure ldap.example.io so that if a user is not found, instead of failing authentication, an attempt is made using ldap.example.com? This way an application using the OpenLDAP server for authentication only needs to be aware of a single LDAP resource.

I imagine there are complications to consider (e.g. duplicate usernames, where do new users get added, should the grafted tree be read-only) but for now I just want to find out if such a mechanism even exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the process is called "referral" and is a pretty standard LDAP operation mode, see http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/referrals.html

An alternative would be chaining: http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Chaining

Comment: Does the referral and chaining work in the case where the two directories share the same DIT ? If it's for production/testing directories, it is likely that there will be the same DIT with test users in testing and production ones in production, but there will likely be no subtree for a referral

Comment: I answer to myself, the documentation states : `The server uses this information [referral uri] to generate referrals for operations acting upon entries not within or subordinate to any of the naming contexts held by the server`. So it should work even if the DIT is exactly the same. Never used referral without a dedicated subtree held by another directory ;)